# I can't see my bootable USB

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I try to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 in a Sony Vaio computer, but I can not choose to boot from a USB memory because it does not appears in the boot menu.

Can you help me?

Comment: No, that is not the problem, I have my USB already booted

Answer (score 0):

modern PC should have the option like **USB HDD**, then move it up to the boot list according the bios tip. at the same time make sure the usb stick is booteable.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have already changed the boot list and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

- Check the flags on the USB Whether it's bootable ,
- Check if your boot loader is UEFI and if it is, change it to legacy.
- Ensure the option in the BIOS to boot from USB is enabled.

Then try to boot again